# Evil Hangman function to return list of letter positions in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I have this *Evil Hangman* project. It works with a Game Manager function which keeps the number of guesses, etc. My assignment is to complete the `wordMaker` class for cheating hangman, based on the following description:

> Take the example of a 4-letter English dictionary that consists of the
> following words:
>
> ```
> ALLY BETA COOL DEAL ELSE FLEW GOOD HOPE IBEX
> ```
>
> The word-guesser guesses the letter "E". The program needs to then
> identify the E’s in the word that the program has "selected". Of
> course, the program hasn’t yet selected a word, and so the program has
> multiple options about where to reveal the E’s. Here’s the above word
> list, with E’s highlighted in each word:
>
> ```
> ALLY BETA COOL DEAL ELSE FLEW GOOD HOPE IBEX
> ```
>
> Notice that each word falls into one of the aforementioned subsets:
>
> - `----`, which contains ALLY, COOL, and GOOD.
> - `-E--`, containing BETA and DEAL.
> - `--E-`, containing FLEW and IBEX.
> - `E--E`, containing ELSE.
> - `---E`, containing HOPE.
>
> The program can now choose to reveal one of the five letter placements
> that corresponds to a subset of the dictionary. There are multiple
> approaches that one could take. You could pick `--E-` because FLEW and
> IBEX are difficult words to guess.
>
> However, to make the project well-defined, we will pick the letter
> placement that **maximizes** the length of the remaining set of words.
> In the case of a tie, we should prefer the letter family with the
> fewest letters, since it reveals as little information as possible to
> the guesser.
>
> Also, if `----` is one of those tied sets, it should be most
> preferred, because it will cost the word-guesser a strike. Otherwise,
> if there is a tie between two word families with equal amounts of
> letters (e.g. `-E--` and `---E`), then either set can be picked.
>
> In the example above, the program should choose to reveal no E’s,
> leaving us with the following words:
>
> ```
> ALLY COOL GOOD
> ```
>
> This choice would give a strike to the word-guesser, marking their
> guess as incorrect. Let’s proceed with this example one more time. If
> the word-guesser now guesses the letter ’O,’ your program will create
> two subsets:
>
> - `-OO-`, containing COOL and GOOD.
> - `----`, containing ALLY.
>
> The first of the two lists is larger, and so the program should reveal
> both O's.
>
> Note that the word-maker does not have access to the number of guesses
> remaining, so it cannot intelligently pick `----` if it is the
> guesser’s final guess and there are words in that subset.

#### My approach

I wrote a couple of functions: `init`, `get_valid_word`, `get_letter_positions_in_word`, `get_remaining_words`, and `guess` (the main part). The `guess` function gets a `guess_letter` and returns a list of letter positions:

```py
    def guess(self, guess_letter) -> list[int]:        
        for word in self.word_list: #word_list is the list of words with the specified word length
            key = self.get_letter_positions_in_word(word, guess_letter) # the function returns a tuple of letter positions in a word
            self.word_families[key].append(word) # creates a default dictionary with letter positions as keys, and words as values

       # this part find the dictionary value set with max number of words
        max_count_dict = defaultdict(list)
        max_count_dict = {k: len(v) for k, v in self.word_families.items()}
        max_count_key = max(max_count_dict, key=max_count_dict.get)
        self.word_list = self.word_families[max_count_key] # this is supposed to be the word family to word with


        return list(max_count_key) # returns the key (letter position) that has the highest count of words
```

#### Problem

The problem is it works for 1 letter, but when I test with more than 1 letter, it fails. It seems it goes to some infinite loop or something.

Initially, I had a separate list for the word list with the highest count. Now I tried to have the same list since the words were not eliminated from the initial list.

Comment: Without knowing the exact requirements of your Evil Hangman, pinpointing the exact problem is difficult. However, I can see why your `guess` function may lead to an "infinite" loop. For each new `guess_letter`, you increase the size of some values in `self.word_families` (see the line that you `append` a word in the for loop). At the end, you update `self.word_list` with an expanded value from `self.word_families`. This means each time you call `guess`, `self.word_list` becomes bigger. If your word lists is large, I can imagine the loop gets "very heavy" after only a few calls to `guess`.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I added a quick example to my question